# React State doesn't change when I click on a div which exists outside the root node

Tags: reactjs

I have this code in react. While clicking on the target div, I want to change the state of the the App component. But it seems that the state never changes and i cant figure out why this is case. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
function App() {

const [var1, serVar1] = useState(true);
const ref1 = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    ref1.current = document.getElementById("target");
    ref1.current.addEventListener("click", () => {
      serVar1(!var1);
    });
  }, []);


  console.log(var1);

  return (
    <div className="App">

    </div>
  );
}
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="target">ssssssss</div>
  </body>
```

Comment: why do you want `target` outside of root?

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz lets say is just a bad scenario im dealing with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `useEffect` in this way:

```
useEffect(() => {

    function handleClick() {
      serVar1(!var1);
    }
    ref1.current = document.getElementById("target");
    ref1.current.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
    return () => {
      ref1.current.removeEventListener("click", handleClick)
    }
  });
```

Comment: useEffect with an empty array executes once. And the value of the props/state/ect ... will be captured only once. so the `var1` value never updates. but in this way every time the function runs, a new callback function will be passed into the event listener with fresh values. more details: https://overreacted.io/how-are-function-components-different-from-classes/

Comment: @EhsanMajdabadi IMO, you don't need to re-run this and assign new listener. You just need to register the onclick listener once and then use `serVar1(v => !v)` to always get current value and toggle it.

Comment: @Zohaib liaz Yes. If we use the overload of the setState which takes a function and provides the previous state, it will work too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use React Portals. You have not explained your whole problem, why do you need this? Do you exactly want click listener on `target` div or it can some child element.

Here is a piece of code which can help you to think in that way and come up with right solution.

```js
function App() {

  const [var1, serVar1] = useState(true);

  
  const doSomething = () => {
    serVar1(v => !v);
  }


  console.log(var1);

  return (
    <div className="App">
     <h1>{var1 ? 'True' : 'False'}</h1>
     {ReactDOM.createPortal(
      <button onClick={doSomething} >Click Me / Toggle var1</button>,
      document.getElementByID('target'),
    )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I want an outer element such as the target div to be able to change the state of the app component. Your case doesnt help either because i want the click action to be on the target div itself